# Representation theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone help me prove the uniqueness part of this theorem? I got the existence down.

**Theorem:** Let $\psi:V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be linear. Then $\exists \ !$ $x\in V$ such that $\psi(v)=x\cdot v \ \ \forall \ \ v\in V$. (There exists a unique vector $x$ such that $\psi(v)=x\cdot v$ for every vector $v$, with $x,v \in V.$

($x\cdot v$ represents the dot product of $x$ and $v$.)

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried the obvious approach? that is: assume that $x$ and $x'$ are such that $\psi(v)=xv$ and $\psi(v)=x'v$, try to prove that $x=x'$.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense to me as written.  Can you rewrite it?  Be more clear about where $x$ and $v$ lie.

Comment: And I think that your last $x$ is a typo.

Comment: All, please see edits.

Comment: @DKal I have tried the obvious approach, should it be that simple?

Comment: Oh, now it makes sense.  You can use \cdot for dot product $\cdot$

Comment: @Seth Thanks, I didn't know that.

Comment: @Anonymous, copper.hat's answer is exactly what I meant by "the obvious approach" as you can see.

Comment: I am good at obvious :-).

Comment: @copper.hat, I hope that one day I'll be as good as you at obvious :)

Comment: Obvious just means 'it has been proved' :-).

Comment: @Dkal I believe that is called the "direct approach", not "the obvious approach" =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\phi(x) = \langle x_1, v\rangle = \langle x_2, v\rangle$ for all $v$.
In particular, $\langle x_2 - x_1, v\rangle = 0$ for all $v$. Letting $v= x_2 - x_1$ gives $\|x_2 - x_1\| = 0$, hence $x_1=x_2$.